# Problem in l3bootstrap.sty, not compiling?

Tags: compiling, expl3

I am trying to compile a tex document using PCTeX, but I get the error appears on the package file (l3bootstrap.sty) as it shown in the image below, I dont know whats the problem here, why is there an error in the package file >> any HELP![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SFYI.png)

Answer (score 5):

PCTeX does not have the e-TeX extensions, or at least did not last time I checked. As such, it cannot be used with `expl3`, which *requires* e-TeX and `\pdfstrcmp`.

You also have a *very* old version of `expl3`: up-to-date versions check for e-TeX and issue an error if they are not available. The later versions also feature a single file containing all of the code.